# fastest way to copy from text file and paste into QListWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

i have QListWidget that load from file strings , each string in the file converted to item in the QListWidget.
now i need to be able copy from text numbers of line to clipbord and paste them into the QListWidget
and it will add items into the QListWidget .
how can i do the copy / paste function is there any tutorial or example that show this kind of action ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I rightly understood your actions, you want to copy from file, to paste in global clipboard and to insert data from clipboard to QListWidget.
Then, you should read about QClipBoard http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.7.x/qclipboard.html

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way (fastest for writing, not performance-wise) to read lines from a file and load them to a QListWidget is:

```
QFile f;
QListWidget w;

.........

w.addItems(QString(f.readAll()).split('\n'));
```

You can use a `QRegExp` instead of `\n` if you want catch stuff like `\r\n` as well.